# Implement webhooks with ReactJS frontend and NodeJS backend

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, webhooks

I have a ReactJS frontend with a NodeJS backend and I'm trying to implement a 3rd party service: on the documentation of said service it's explained how you can give a URL and the service will use that URL to send an HTTP POST with useful info whenever they detect an event. The way that my app is deployed makes it so *only the frontend can make requests to my backend api*, so I'm not really sure what URL can I give to this 3rd party service.

**What I think could be done**
I could create a new route with react-router and this URL be the one that the 3rd party points to, in this route I'd have a `useEffect()` hook that sends the POST of the 3rd party service to my backend, **the question is**: is this the a normal approach? it seems a little odd to me to have a route with react-router with an empty component that's used to only handle the HTTP POST. Or is there something else that I could do in order to avoid having the frontend as a middleman?

Comment: Why can only the frontend make requests to it?  An API is an API, there's no guarantee that only the frontend is connecting to it.  Is it because the API has an auth layer?  If so, can you disable auth for a specific route and provide that as the webhook?

Comment: @c1moore I've asked the previous person who was working with the project and they mentioned that the deployment on AWS was done so that *only* the frontend would be able to access the backend. This does seem a little odd though, and the project isn't even up at this moment, so I do have to make sure that I understood correctly. If I'm able to make the request directly to the API then there would be no issue. Thank you for your comment

Comment: Unless the frontend is also running in AWS or the frontend can only be accessed while on VPN (or a specific network), I'm still not sure how it could be blocked.  I would ask for some clarification there so you don't build an overly complicated solution.

Comment: @c1moore Yes, they did mentioned that the frontend and the backend were both on AWS, I'd say that this has to do with one being only visible to the other. Something that's a lot more clear to me now is that the approach that I was suggesting is not a good idea at all, and that I need to clarify the situation and look at other approaches that don't involve overcomplicating the situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not the best approach to make it.

I recommend you to create a new service, a proxy service, so you can point this 3rd party service to call your proxy service, and since you have control of your proxy service, you can allow it to call your backend.

You can use node.js to build this proxy service as well.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, the idea here would be to send it directly to my backend, through a proxy, so I don't have to do all the frontend stuff described. This proxy should be exposed as some kind of URL for this to be valid. Do you know of any resources/documentation on how to create these kind of proxies with node?

Comment: Yes, exactly! 

You will expose a URL in your proxy, where this service will make the calls. Since the proxy is yours, you can make validations if the object shape matches as expected, and other verifications.

Then if your proxy is called correctly by the 3rd party service, by your proxy you can call your backend, in this way you don't expose your backend directly for any public call.

About the resource, twillio blog has a great article [about creating proxy with node.js](https://www.twilio.com/blog/node-js-proxy-server)